# VS2010 failing to locate source file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc

My project has following structure:

```
Someproject    
  include    
  workspace
     bin
     projectspace    
  source
```

I am using MFC for dialog based application. I add a new dialog and add a new class.Header and source files are generated in workspace/projectspace folder. I do exclude from project, move the files to respective location (includes/source) and do *Add Existing Items* in VS. Now when I add a button click event from dialog, it creates a new source file in includes directory. How to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

You should not do exclude. Instead, copy the files to the desired location, then remove from the project. Then Add existing from the new location.

Comment: i tried even that.Same results.New file is getting created in includes folder.
1 observation is, if my source file name is Test.cpp,new file got created with the name test.CPP